# How to decorate property with ExpandableObject in C#

Tags: c#, properties, decorator

I am trying to display this class instance in the Xceed PropertyGrid per [the instructions here](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PropertyGrid#expandable_properties):

```
    PG.SelectedObject = new Order()
        {
            ShipAddress = "Luisenstr. 48",
            ShipCountry = "Germany",
            ShipName = "Toms Spezialitaten",
            ShipPostalCode = "44087",
            chronology = new OrderChronology()
            {
                OrderDate = new DateTime(1996, 7, 5),
                ShippedDate = new DateTime(1996, 8, 16)
            }

        };
```

The Xceed example for  behavior analogous to what I am trying to do says `you must decorate your property with the ExpandableObject attribute.` and shows this:

```
       public class Person
    {
        [Category("Information")]
        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        [Description("This property uses a TextBox as the default editor.")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Category("Conections")]
        [Description("This property is a complex property and has no default editor.")]


        [ExpandableObject]
        public Person Spouse { get; set; }
    }
```

When I try to do the same with my class (see below) it causes a compiler error; it does not like `[ExpandableObject]` and hints that I may be `missing a using directive or assembly reference`. Am I?

```
 public class Order
  {

    public string ShipAddress { get; set; }
    public string ShipCountry { get; set; }
    public String ShipName { get; set; }
    public String ShipPostalCode { get; set; }

    [ExpandableObject]
    public OrderChronology chronology; 
  }

   public class OrderChronology
   {
      public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
      public DateTime ShippedDate { get; set; }
   }
```

Comment: Like the other said you have to add the reference to the assembly and then include the using statement. I would like to add to that by saying that if you are using Visual Studio and you are using something that isn't recognized, for example the ExpandableObject attribute in your case, you can hit CTRL+.  (dot)  and it will try to resolve it for you and give you the option to include a using statement automatically or use the fully qualified name instead.

Comment: It's a shame you can't do this without having to modify the types you want to inspect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add assembly `Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.dll` and after that you should add following namespace:

```
using Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.Attributes;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the `Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.Attributes` namespace in your `using` statements?