# Xceed WPF PropertyGrid : decorating property with Category : compiler error

Tags: wpf-controls, propertygrid, xceed

I have basically the same question as the one I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16595055/how-to-decorate-property-with-expandableobject-in-c-sharp). Adding the `using Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.Attributes` directive solved that.

This time, the compiler does not like `[Category("Shipping")]` decoration.

```
        [Category("Shipping")]
        public string ShipAddress { get; set; }
```

How can I deduce or determine what namespace needs to be included when I run into obstacles like this?

Here are the using directives I've included already:

```
using Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid;
using Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.Editors;
using Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.Commands;
using Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.Converters;
using Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.PropertyGrid.Attributes;
```

The xaml is this:

```
 <xctk:PropertyGrid  AutoGenerateProperties="True" Name="XPG1" IsCategorized="True" />
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an older question, but since it's unanswered I thought it would be helpful to provide one anyway. In this case you need the following using statement:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
```

In general, the best way to figure out what namespace or using statement you need is to look for the name of the attribute in the Object Browser under the Xceed namespace, and if you can't find it there, on Google.

One thing to remember - while it shows up as just `[Category]` in code, the actual name of the class will be `CategoryAttribute`.

Comment: Still relevant in 2017